# How to center table with caption spanning through whole page

Tags: css, html-table, centering

I have many tables in my webpages that I need to center with their captions. Setting the `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties mostly works; however, many of these tables are also narrow, and the captions only get as wide as the tables.

[Example at codepen.io](https://codepen.io/flirora/pen/YzQKxap)

[image: Screenshot of the example]

Here's what I tried:

- Explicitly setting the width of the caption (`width: 100%`): this just makes the table off-center because the `thead` and `tbody` elements within the `table` are not centered.
  [image: Screenshot of setting the width of the caption explicitly (with min-width: 30%;)]
- Setting the table to use the flexbox model (`display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;`): `thead` and `tbody` are not aligned with each other, and this doesn't respect the caption's `caption-side` property.
  [image: Screenshot of setting the table to use the flexbox model]

---

The screenshot below (rendered in LaTeX) shows what I want in terms of alignment.

[image: What I want in terms of alignment (LaTeX rendering)]

Is there a way to have both the table and caption centered, while dealing with narrow tables gracefully?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can reliably get the layout you're after, using `<caption>`. User agents aren't 100% consistent in where the caption is rendered with respect to the table. Is `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` an option? It's probably a better semantic match for how you're using it, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay! Try using `<figcaption>`. Here is the modified version of your code.

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

figcaption {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align : center;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <table id="vowel-derivs-0-1-5">
    
    <thead><tr><th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>o</td><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>o</td><td>e</td><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>i</td><td>i</td><td>e</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <figcaption>Table 3: Thematic vowel derivatives for paradigms 0, 1, and 5.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

I hope you have found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you may also use a pseudo oversized to increase table's width:

example forked from you pen:

```css
table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr::before,
tr::after {
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
th {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
th,
td {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

caption {
  caption-side: bottom;
  padding: 0.3em;
}
```

```html
<table id="vowel-derivs-0-1-5">
  <caption>Table 3: Thematic vowel derivatives for paradigms 0, 1, and 5.</caption>
  <thead><tr><th>0</th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>o</td><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>o</td><td>e</td><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>e</td><td>i</td><td>i</td><td>i</td><td>e</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This has a problem: wide tables are artificially narrowed to make room for the `tr::before` and `tr::after` cells.

Comment: @bb94 indeed, but you are not giving any width to the table. % has no real reference to be calculated from, so those virtual cells are only stretch by the browser trying to evaluate a valid value .but  do not use a value over 50% ;) here a fiddle to easily  shrink the visual to the content of the table and see how it behaves  https://jsfiddle.net/r2hnbwox/